# Jquery UI slider, adding and removing handles

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, handle

I am in need of some assistance. I have been searching for a solution for days and it seems there is no solution, at least not with jquery.

I need a query UI slider with which I can add or remove handles on the fly. And if I create a new handle I need to find that specific one so I can manipulate it.

Heres a super easy http://jsfiddle.net/t0vy920c/.

```
$(".slider").slider({
    min:0,
    max:100,
    steps:1,
    values: [10, 50, 70,90]
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0vy920c/)

I think I need to change the `values` parameter but I need to change its length, not its value. And I need to know which handle was created. I'm still pretty new when it comes to jquery UI, so any help would be appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question right, you just need to reinitialize slider on whatever event you want to add new item like:

```
$('button').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".slider").slider("destroy");
    values.push(val);
    values = values.sort();
    $(".slider").slider({
        min:0,
        max:100,
        steps:20,
        values: values   
     })
})
```

Here is some [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0vy920c/3/)

**UPD** added [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0vy920c/4/) with adding class to new element

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help. In your fiddle you used var val = 23; to add a new handle. Is there a way for me to find the  handle that was created this way. I need to give it a class since I'm doing this with several sliders and i need to group those handles. I don't want to find it based on its value, in case there are other handles with the same value.